# nhibernate libraries for medium trust environment

Tags: nhibernate, medium-trust

There have been so many discussions about this topic [nhibernate for medium trust]. Keen to know if there is a location where Nhibernate and dependent libraries compatible for medium trust are available.

That would be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact, there is a place to get the files to run NHibernate in a medium trust environment without doing something crazy like disabling lazy loading. I wrote a blog post about it and have provided the link below.

[How To Run NHibernate In A Medium Trust Environment Easily And Quickly](http://iamdotnetcrazy.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-to-get-fluent-nhibernate-nhibernate.html?showComment=1291086816617#c1146478645767384493)

Getting the files is very simple so please have a look.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Kila Morton, Got the libraries at following, and it worked too. http://blog.yeticode.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/downloads/2010/06/libs.zip (Thanking John for the same... http://blog.yeticode.co.uk/2010/03/running-nhibernate-in-medium-trust/)